# ToString() method culture-based in web application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

For instance:

```
double d = 2.24;
```

If Culture is 'fr'

```
d.ToString() -> "2,24"
```

If culture is 'en'

```
d.ToString() -> "2.24"
```

This implicit culture-based cast can generate lot of mistakes.

In aspx.cs

```
<script>
var n = <% Response.Write(d.ToString()); %> // if 'fr' n = 2,24 -> js syntax error
</script>
```

We can avoid that with

```
Convert.ToString(d, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Is there any option to made this `InvariantCulture` by default for ToString()?

Any idea why it is done by Default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`<globalization>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0.aspx) element of your web.config and set a culture and a UI culture. For example:

```
<system.web>
    <globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en-US">
</system.web>
```

By the way instead of:

```
<script>
    var n = <% Response.Write(d.ToString()); %> // if 'fr' n = 2,24 -> js syntax error
</script>
```

I would recommend you to always use [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) in order to JSON serialize the value when passing data to javascript:

```
<script>
    var n = <%= new JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(d) %>;
</script>
```